# Caffe-segnet: redefinition of argument 'compiler-bindir'

Tags: makefile, caffe

It's been days trying to compile caffe-segnet, and now stuck at this error, I m using gcc `gcc (Ubuntu 4.8.5-4ubuntu8) 4.8.5`
 to compile [caffe-segnet](https://github.com/alexgkendall/caffe-segnet). I'm using **Cuda 9.0**, **cudnn v2** and **opencv 3.3.0** as mentionned in the documentation of caffe and opencv. Disabling `cudnn` or not in the `Makefile.config` doesn't change anything as mentioned [here](https://github.com/BVLC/caffe/issues/3671#issuecomment-191279655).

Before that I was using cuda 10.0 and cudnn 7.0 and deleted all because when starting my model there was so many errors. Here is the output error when using `make all`:

```
CXX src/caffe/common.cpp
/usr/bin/g++-4.8 src/caffe/common.cpp -pthread -fPIC -DNDEBUG -O2 -I/usr/include/python2.7 -I/usr/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/numpy/core/include -I/usr/local/include -I/usr/local/hdf5 -I/usr/local/hdf5/include -I.build_release/src -I./src -I./include -I/usr/local/cuda/include -Wall -Wno-sign-compare -std=c++11 -MMD -MP -pthread -fPIC -DNDEBUG -O2 -I/usr/include/python2.7 -I/usr/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/numpy/core/include -I/usr/local/include -I/usr/local/hdf5 -I/usr/local/hdf5/include -I.build_release/src -I./src -I./include -I/usr/local/cuda/include -Wall -Wno-sign-compare -c -o .build_release/src/caffe/common.o 2> .build_release/src/caffe/common.o.warnings.txt \
    || (cat .build_release/src/caffe/common.o.warnings.txt; exit 1)
CXX src/caffe/internal_thread.cpp
/usr/bin/g++-4.8 src/caffe/internal_thread.cpp -pthread -fPIC -DNDEBUG -O2 -I/usr/include/python2.7 -I/usr/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/numpy/core/include -I/usr/local/include -I/usr/local/hdf5 -I/usr/local/hdf5/include -I.build_release/src -I./src -I./include -I/usr/local/cuda/include -Wall -Wno-sign-compare -std=c++11 -MMD -MP -pthread -fPIC -DNDEBUG -O2 -I/usr/include/python2.7 -I/usr/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/numpy/core/include -I/usr/local/include -I/usr/local/hdf5 -I/usr/local/hdf5/include -I.build_release/src -I./src -I./include -I/usr/local/cuda/include -Wall -Wno-sign-compare -c -o .build_release/src/caffe/internal_thread.o 2> .build_release/src/caffe/internal_thread.o.warnings.txt \
    || (cat .build_release/src/caffe/internal_thread.o.warnings.txt; exit 1)
NVCC src/caffe/layers/upsample_layer.cu
/usr/local/cuda/bin/nvcc -D_FORCE_INLINES -ccbin=/usr/bin/g++-4.8 -Xcompiler -fPIC -DNDEBUG -O2 -I/usr/include/python2.7 -I/usr/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/numpy/core/include -I/usr/local/include -I/usr/local/hdf5 -I/usr/local/hdf5/include -I.build_release/src -I./src -I./include -I/usr/local/cuda/include -std=c++11 -ccbin=/usr/bin/g++-4.8 -Xcompiler -fPIC -DNDEBUG -O2 -I/usr/include/python2.7 -I/usr/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/numpy/core/include -I/usr/local/include -I/usr/local/hdf5 -I/usr/local/hdf5/include -I.build_release/src -I./src -I./include -I/usr/local/cuda/include  -M src/caffe/layers/upsample_layer.cu -o .build_release/cuda/src/caffe/layers/upsample_layer.d \
    -odir .build_release/cuda/src/caffe/layers
nvcc fatal   : redefinition of argument 'compiler-bindir'
Makefile:544: recipe for target '.build_release/cuda/src/caffe/layers/upsample_layer.o' failed
make: *** [.build_release/cuda/src/caffe/layers/upsample_layer.o] Error 1
```

and the line 544 in `Makefile` which the error come from:

```
...
    @ cat $@.$(WARNS_EXT)

$(BUILD_DIR)/cuda/%.o: %.cu | $(ALL_BUILD_DIRS)
544>    @ echo NVCC $<
    $(Q)$(CUDA_DIR)/bin/nvcc $(NVCCFLAGS) $(CUDA_ARCH) -M $< -o ${@:.o=.d} \
        -odir $(@D)
...
```

> Notice that I tried compiling it with gcc 5 and gcc 7 and the same error occur ! Any idea guys ?

**EDIT 1:**
I also added this `CUSTOM_CXX := /usr/bin/g++-4.8` to `Makefile.config`

Answer (score 0):

Since no one aswered I finaly found a solution, the error is caused because the same argument is called twice, in my `Makefile` I added those lines of code:

```sh
CXXFLAGS += -pthread -fPIC $(COMMON_FLAGS) $(WARNINGS) -std=c++11
NVCCFLAGS += -D_FORCE_INLINES -ccbin=$(CXX) -Xcompiler -fPIC $(COMMON_FLAGS) -std=c++11
LINKFLAGS += -pthread -fPIC $(COMMON_FLAGS) $(WARNINGS) -std=c++11
```

to avoid this error `/usr/include/c++/4.8/bits/c++0x_warning.h:32:2: error: #error This file requires compiler and library support for the ISO C++ 2011 standard. This support is currently experimental, and must be enabled with the -std=c++11 or -std=gnu++11 compiler options.`

In the same file *in the complete build flags*, we have the same flag:

```sh
...
# Complete build flags.
COMMON_FLAGS += $(foreach includedir,$(INCLUDE_DIRS),-I$(includedir))
CXXFLAGS += -pthread -fPIC $(COMMON_FLAGS) $(WARNINGS)
NVCCFLAGS += -ccbin=$(CXX) -Xcompiler -fPIC $(COMMON_FLAGS)
# mex may invoke an older gcc that is too liberal with -Wuninitalized
...
```

what I did is commenting my flag I added:

```sh
CXXFLAGS += -pthread -fPIC $(COMMON_FLAGS) $(WARNINGS) -std=c++11
#NVCCFLAGS += -D_FORCE_INLINES -ccbin=$(CXX) -Xcompiler -fPIC $(COMMON_FLAGS) -std=c++11
LINKFLAGS += -pthread -fPIC $(COMMON_FLAGS) $(WARNINGS) -std=c++11
```

and add `-std=c++11` argument to `NVCCFLAGS` in the *complete build flags* section, it turned to be something like this:

```sh
...
# Complete build flags.
COMMON_FLAGS += $(foreach includedir,$(INCLUDE_DIRS),-I$(includedir))
CXXFLAGS += -pthread -fPIC $(COMMON_FLAGS) $(WARNINGS)
NVCCFLAGS += -ccbin=$(CXX) -Xcompiler -fPIC $(COMMON_FLAGS) -std=c++11
# mex may invoke an older gcc that is too liberal with -Wuninitalized
...
```

> Before doing a `make all` after editing your Makefile, make sure you do a `make clean` or you'll get the same error !